# changing lab during PhD

Tags: phd, advisor

I have started my PhD recently (4 months back). I did not enroll at university yet due to technical reasons. From the start I was having second thoughts about the institute and place and it feels like I should have gone to a better group or better institute. It is a new lab, with a new PI so I cannot comment on the lab culture or working environment yet.

I just want to know from other experienced people why you should **not** switch labs during PhD or what should **not** be the factor affecting your decision to switch lab during PhD?

Comment: How can you have started a PhD, yet not enrolled anywhere?